# Ubuntu 16.04 shows only wallpaper, cursor and flashing icons

Tags: dual-boot, nvidia, uefi, desktop-background, flicker

I have recently installed ubuntu on a dual boot system with UEFI. The installation went fine, without any problems and was performed from cd by creating the partitions swap,root and home.

However, after I put the password to log in, only the wallpaper and the cursor do remain and the icons flash very fast in and out of existence.
 This also means that i cannot open the terminal since it doesn't appear and/or it flickers too. 
I suspect it has to do with some graphic driver not being implemented (I have a nvidia gtx 1060 if it can help) but I don't know what to do.

Any help would be very welcome, please ask me for any further detail it might be necessary to address this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Disable Secure Boot in BIOS. With Secure Boot enabled proprietary drivers will never load. Then run in a terminal

```
sudo apt purge 'nvidia.*'
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nvidia-367 nvidia-prime
```

The 367 driver is a recommended by Nvidia LTS driver.